# Tizen native app: Getting Panel from SplitPanel

Tags: panel, tizen, tizen-native-app, splitpanel

i'm trying to get a particular panel from a panel done with the UI designer, this panel is a Panel control my code is something like

firstly i've tried with

Code:

```
Panel* pPanel=static_cast< Panel* >(pSplitPanel->getPane(Tizen::Ui::Controls::SplitPanelPaneOrder::SPLIT_PANEL_PANE_ORDER_SECOND))
```

Code:

```
Tizen::Ui::Control* pControl=pSplitPanel->getPane(Tizen::Ui::Controls::SplitPanelPaneOrder::SPLIT_PANEL_PANE_ORDER_SECOND)
```

`getPane` function returns a `Control*` pointer but as i'm trying to get it into a `pControl` or a `pPanel` variable it gives me an error and i cant get it any idea?

Comment: _"it gives me an error"_. And what is the error exactly?

Comment: I'm away from my laptop so i am not able to remember that error, i'll tell you the error on a couple hours, thanks in advance

Comment: Solved i was mispelling library reference my error was 'class expected' now i'm trying to get a button inside of that panel